# Emberjs live serverside validation

Tags: forms, validation, ember.js

I've managed to get the input going to my server, and the server responding if the input is valid, or returning an error object if not.

I'm just not sure how to use the returned error object to actually do something. There are many examples around the internet of how to loop through the error object and display the message but that isn't exactly what I'm after.

I have a form component which has a bunch of fields that look like:

```
{{input type="text" value=account.twitterId class="input" focus-out="validateInput"}}
```

and validateInput in the component looks like

```
validateInput() {
  let account = get(this, 'account');

  account.save().then(() => {
    console.log('success!'); // add class to the input field
  }).catch((adapterError) => {
    console.log(account.get('errors')); // add different class to the input field
    console.log(adapterError);
  });
},
```

As mentioned above, this triggers and either returns successful or error message

But how do I take the result and use it to add classes to the class key of the input field?

I did attempt with the following

```
  hasError: false,

  actions: {

  validateInput() {
    let account = get(this, 'account');

    account.save().then(() => {
      set(this, 'hasError', false);
    }).catch((adapterError) => {
      set(this, 'hasError', true);
    });
  },
```

}

And then a if statement in the front, which kind of worked but didn't re-trigger if the user changes the input for a second time.

Am I supposed to use a computed property for this? If so how would one look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your plan should work. I've created an Ember Twiddle that you can use as a reference. I tweaked the model a little to allow for random success / failure promises coming back from a `save()` method, but the rest is pretty identical to what you posted. Open your console while tabbing out of the twiddle to see the result of the promise being returned. I use a template conditional like you recommended to hide/show some feedback to the user.

https://ember-twiddle.com/3398d28381a4c0afb71cb5d59f271e36

Let me know if you have any questions between your implementation and what I have in the twiddle. ✌

Comment: Thanks for confirming that it should work, and it does infact work as expected. Question though; how would I make it reusable for multiple fields? Obviously having a single variable means all fields act the same regardless of which field is actually being edited...

Comment: Updated twiddle, is that what you were after? Basically, it's a component that takes a "saveable" (anything with a save method that returns a promise, ie: any of the ember data models). You can pass in the same account to both, and both will validate based on their independent responses (open console to see the result). Keep in mind though that sending out all these network requests might result in excess network round trips (and if any of these depend on each other it gets hairy). Avoiding a round trip with something like `ember-cp-validations` for "in-app" validations might be an option.